# Block internet access to OpenVPN clients once connected to the VPN - Access server in AWS

Tags: routing, openvpn

I have an OpenVPN access server running in AWS - the instance is built using the official AMI from the marketplace. There is a requirement to block the internet access for all clients once they are connected to VPN. Means, once connected, they should only be routed to the VPC networks.

How can I achieve this:

1) without Making any changes in the client side config

2) without making any changes in the OS level routes in access server (if no other choice, can explore this)

Split tunneling is not an option, blocking the internet access of the access server is also not an option in this case.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Push the default route to the clients via the VPN to the AWS host (add `push "redirect-gateway def1"` to your server.conf file).

Then set the firewall on the AWS host to only allow access to subnet you want clients to have access.

Comment: If the host do not have a route to the internet, how can the clients connect to it ?

Comment: The VPN server host still has a route to the internet, It is just choosing not to route packets that come in over the VPN out to the internet

Answer (score 0):

This OpenVPN config results in clients using conventional routing for the rest of Internet packets but then routing all business-related traffic (in this case, `10.8.0.0/24`), through the actual VPN.

I've managed to put together this `server.conf`. I pasted all the file and commented all the lines I changed or added, and also because of order.

```
port 1194
proto udp6
dev tun
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
keepalive 10 120
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
client-to-client  # Otherwise, clients may not be able to connect but to the server.
push "route 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.255 10.8.0.1 1"  # Push default VPN route for
                                                  #  redirecting internal traffic 
                                                  #  only
# push "route <network_ip> <netmask> <gateway, normally, the server> <priority>"
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
#push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"  # Comment out so clients won't get DNS config 
                                 # changed.
#push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"  # Ditto
#push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"  # Comment out so clients won't get 
                                           #  their default routing changed, 
                                           #  thus redirecting even Internet 
                                           #  packets.
server-ipv6 fd42:42:42:42::/112
tun-ipv6
push tun-ipv6
#push "route-ipv6 2000::/3"  # Disable Internet IPv6 addresses routing
#push "redirect-gateway ipv6"  # So no IPv6 routing override.
dh none
ecdh-curve prime256v1
tls-crypt tls-crypt.key
crl-verify crl.pem
ca ca.crt
cert server_P0QFYDE85qRItX6k.crt
key server_P0QFYDE85qRItX6k.key
auth SHA256
cipher AES-128-GCM
ncp-ciphers AES-128-GCM
tls-server
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-cipher TLS-ECDHE-ECDSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256
client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/ccd
status /var/log/openvpn/status.log
verb 3
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Of course it isn't suitable. Thanks for the feedback. I might only have the configs necessary for redirecting private traffic, but I thought it was a good idea to paste all the file and comment added or changed lines.

Comment: Do you think it's any clearer now?